# Creating fillable PDF form with dynamically updated fields

Tags: ubuntu, libreoffice

Is there a way to create fillable PDF forms where a set of fields gets their data when one of the fields is filled out?

The normal use case would be application form, where your name or membership number has to be entered on the top of each page.

I am using LibreOffice 3.5.4.2. In a earlier version I was able to get the desired effect if I left the field names to be the same (i.e. the field names as seen in the Form Navigator). I'm open for using any free software tool.

There is a similiar question asked [elsewhere](http://ask.libreoffice.org/question/3295/form-fields-cross-referenced-throughout-document/) at ask.libreoffice.org.

**CLARIFICATION**:
The above actually works in some newer versions of Adobe Acrobat, but I haven't been able to test across different versions and found that it didn't work in version 5.0.

I've tested with PDF readers such as Evince and Okular using Ubuntu 12.04, but here the above doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Give the different form fields the same unique name, ans when exporting choose "Allow duplicate field names". This answered the question I had.

[image]